# Extract name and version number, and avoid mismatch?

Tags: python, regex, string, version-control

I want to extract software name and its version from the the filename so that I could filter the latest version of software. The filename is organized as `name-version.crate`, but both `name` and `version` could include `-`.

I tried use regex to extract version first, and then use find to locate the `-` that separate `name` from `version`, it seems work for most cases, but failed to deal with those names having `-number` styles.

My code is like this

```
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
import re

reg_str = r'(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[+.-](?P<crate>.*)'
org_str = r'\s*-([\d.]+)'

def demo(crate):   
    tmp = crate[:-6]
    verstr =""
    try:
        #verstr = re.search(reg_str, tmp).group(1)
        x = re.search(reg_str, tmp)
        verstr = x.group('version')
        print(x.group('name')),
        print(verstr),
        print(x.group('crate'))
        dash_location = crate.find(verstr)
        name = crate[:dash_location-1]
        #version = StrictVersion(verstr)
    except NameError:
        print("NameError in StrictVersion for ({}), verstr is ({})".format(crate, verstr))
    except:
        print("Exception StrictVersion for ({}), verstr is ({})".format(crate, verstr))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cases = ["substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate","google-reseller1_sandbox-cli-0.3.6+20160329.crate","tis-100-0.1.3.crate"]
    for i in cases:
        demo(i)
```

Some test cases that causes exception:

```
substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate
google-reseller1_sandbox-cli-0.3.6+20160329.crate
tis-100-0.1.3.crate
```

I am using `python-3.6`, and `StrictVersion` is used to compare the versions.

Comment: Please check [`(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[+.-](?P<crate>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/i4tS4I/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. But your reg string still failed to resolve `tis-100-0.1.3.crate` properly. Besides, I think the right version should be `0.3.6+20160329` and `0.4.1-pre.1`, but you discard the strings after `+/-`, right?

Comment: What is the rule? What is the required output per input string? `name-version.crate` "formula" is too vague to provide a valid answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is named under `name-version.crate`, I'm not sure about the strict rules. I think one proper is to locate the right `-`. And the regex string you provided works well to locate the right `-`, except for `tis-100-0.1.3.crate`

Comment: Aren't `tis-100`, `0.1.3` and `crate` expected group values? See [`(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+[^.]*)\.(?P<crate>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/i4tS4I/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is.  But an exception was throwed, let me check. Thanks.

Comment: Here are the relevant files referred in your test case:
https://github.com/Byron/google-apis-rs/blob/master/gen/reseller1_sandbox-cli/Cargo.toml

https://github.com/emk/substudy/blob/v0.4.1-pre.1/Cargo.toml

https://github.com/rcolinray/tis-100-rs/blob/master/Cargo.toml

Comment: See http://ideone.com/AFNv74

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. I was wrong because I was testing under python 2.7. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks @Richard . According the the pages, the version should include be `0.4.1-pre.1` for `substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, as informed by Richard, the correct version name should be "0.3.6+20160329" and "0.4.1-pre.1" for `google-reseller1_sandbox-cli-0.3.6+20160329.crate` and `substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate`. Would you please change your answer to only extract (`name` and `version`) instead of (`name`, `version` and `crate`)?

Comment: So, `(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d[^.]*)` is enough, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it works.

Comment: Wait, I think it does not, see [how `substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate` is parsed into `substudy`, `0.4.1-pre` and `.1.crate`](https://regex101.com/r/fIwAIs/1). Looks like you need to grab the 2nd capture up to the last dot. It seems [`(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d.*)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/fIwAIs/2) is a better option, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d[^.]*)\.(?P<crate>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i4tS4I/4).

**Details**:

- `(?P<name>.*)`  - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `-` - hyphen
- `(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d[^.]*)` - 1+ digits, `.`, 1+ digits, `.`, 1 digit and then 0+ chars other than `.` up to a...
- `\.`  - a dot
- `(?P<crate>.*)` - all the rest of the line.

A [Python demo](http://ideone.com/AFNv74):

```
import re
ss = ['substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate','google-reseller1_sandbox-cli-0.3.6+20160329.crate','tis-100-0.1.3.crate','gobject-2-0-sys-0.46.0.crate']
rx = re.compile(r'(?P<name>.*)-(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d[^.]*)\.(?P<crate>.*)')
for s in ss:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print("------------------")
        print("INPUT: {}".format(s))
        print("NAME: {}".format(m.group("name")))
        print("VERSION: {}".format(m.group("version")))
        print("CRATE: {}".format(m.group("crate")))
```

Output:

```
------------------
INPUT: substudy-0.4.1-pre.1.crate
NAME: substudy
VERSION: 0.4.1-pre
CRATE: 1.crate
------------------
INPUT: google-reseller1_sandbox-cli-0.3.6+20160329.crate
NAME: google-reseller1_sandbox-cli
VERSION: 0.3.6+20160329
CRATE: crate
------------------
INPUT: tis-100-0.1.3.crate
NAME: tis-100
VERSION: 0.1.3
CRATE: crate
------------------
INPUT: gobject-2-0-sys-0.46.0.crate
NAME: gobject-2-0-sys
VERSION: 0.46.0
CRATE: crate
```